# Stop production when receiving pile is full?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

For example, I have a still that I want to *always* produce booze unless a receiving booze pile is full, meaning people don't need more booze. Repeat will repeat forever, regardless the state of the receiving pile.

I don't mind if it requires a plugin. It really ought to be implemented, though. It's basic manufacturing engineering. I also don't mind if I have to switch to the older pre .40 version to work the plugin.

Comment: This is not available in the base game. And because a new version just came out, any such "plugins" that might automate this are also out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DFHack workflow plugin](https://github.com/DFHack/dfhack/blob/master/plugins/workflow.cpp) provides this feature by means of automatically suspending and resuming repeat-jobs based on stock counts, but it can be remarkably complex to configure - and since this is DF, I'm already assuming you have a high tolerance for the complex. :-)

In the absence of such an add-on, once the output stockpile fills, the native dwarven flow control mechanism of [workshop clutter](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Clutter) takes over:

> As the clutter builds and makes it more difficult to move around the
>   workshop, production slows more and more. If demand suddenly spikes,
>   the clutter is removed and production rises again. Some scientists see
>   this as an instinctual supply and demand device. Others see it as dumb
>   luck.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely will work. In fact it is even better than the solution I had thought of, since it works like a thermostat, stopping at a certain maximum, then starting at a certain minimum, which prevents thrashing. I do have another question, though. Can hauling be turned off of the dwarf allowed to work in the workshop while production is required, and turned back on when production is not required?

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist, in that case you're looking for the [DFHack autolabor plugin](https://github.com/DFHack/dfhack/blob/master/plugins/autolabor.cpp) which assigns labors automatically according to individual dwarf skill, job queue depth and configured min/max bounds; any able dwarf not assigned specific labors is assigned hauling.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather not use DFHack, you could possibly do a very hauling-intensive way by having the materials you are going to use placed in the stockpile you want to fill.  If this is booze, then you can just store your barrels in the booze stockpile. You'd need two stockpiles.

Main stockpile:  (You'll have to enable taking from anywhere and barrels only to set it up before you start making booze.  When it's full of empty barrels, put it to these settings:)

- Will take from links only
- Gives to the stills
- Accepts booze and barrels

Plant stockpile:

- Will take from anywhere
- Gives to the stills

This one is needed because otherwise your stills will never take any plants to brew.

Once the main stockpile(s) is full of barrels, flip the settings to those listed and start brewing.  The stills will take barrels only from the stockpiles, but then put the filled barrels back, so that when there are no more empty barrels, they will not take from anywhere else and cancel the brewing job.  You will have to be careful, however, that your stockpile is full of barrels when you begin, or else you'll only get as much made at a time as you have barrels loaded in it when you start brewing.  Also, make sure your plant stockpile is never empty, or the stills will stop too early and you'll have to restart the job, since they won't take the plants to brew from anywhere but the stills.

The vanilla stockpiles can be pretty powerful.

Just sayin'.

Comment: This is a pretty clever way to do it with just the base game, and starting the main stockpile full of barrels and switching the options means that no new empty barrels will come in while others are in use.